# Perform different transformations on different OpenGL objects

Tags: c, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to create a simple game with OpenGL and C, and I've come across a problem. I've set up my projection, view, and model with the cglm library like this:

```c
mat4 projection;
glm_mat4_identity(projection);
glm_perspective(glm_rad(window.fov), (float) window.width / (float) window.height, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);
setShaderMat4(mainShader, "projection", projection);

mat4 view;
glm_mat4_identity(view);
glm_translate(view, (vec3) {0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f});
glm_rotate(view, glm_rad(55.0f), (vec3) {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
setShaderMat4(mainShader, "view", view);

mat4 model;
glm_mat4_identity(model);
glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(90.0f), (vec3) {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});

drawFirstObject(); //Draws a standard OpenGL cube (with vertices, VAOs, EBOs, etc.)

setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);
```

This works, but when I want to draw another object, I'm a bit stuck. I can't just do:

```c
mat4 model;
glm_mat4_identity(model);


glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(90.0f), (vec3) {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}); //Perform first translation on first cube
drawFirstObject();

glm_scale(model, (vec3) {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}); //Perform second translation on second cube
drawSecondObject();

setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);
```

as the translations will be applied to both cubes and **I want to have separate model transformations for separate OpenGL cubes**. I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Do I need to setup a new shader for each new object and setup a new projection, view, and model for each new object as well? I doubt that's the way to approach this issue as this would get cumbersome with a ton of objects.

Any advice or help on solving this issue is appriciated.

Comment: I don't understand how `setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);` is **after** the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of operations is already wrong in the single object version of your code. OpenGL is a state machine, so it only considers matrices that are set **before** the draw command is issued. You have to set the matrix first, then draw your object.

```
mat4 model;
glm_mat4_identity(model);
glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(90.0f), (vec3) {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});

setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);
drawFirstObject(); //Draws a standard OpenGL cube (with vertices, VAOs, EBOs, etc.)
```

Since OpenGL executes commands one after the other, you can then set another matrix and draw a second object with that matrix:

```
mat4 model;
glm_mat4_identity(model);
glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(90.0f), (vec3) {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});

setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);
drawFirstObject(); //Uses the currently set matrix (rotation)

glm_mat4_identity(model); //Reset matrix
glm_scale(model, (vec3) {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}); //Construct second matrix

setShaderMat4(mainShader, "model", model);
drawSecondObject(); //Uses the newly set matrix (scaling)
```

If you want to view both objects from the same camera position and with the same projection, there is no need to set the view/projection matrix again for the second object since the values stay the same.